# python pandas data frame: single column to multiple columns based on values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I am new to pandas.
I am trying to split a single column to multiple columns based on index value using Groupby. Below is the program wrote.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [(0,1.1),
        (1,1.2),
        (2,1.3),
        (0,2.1),
        (1,2.2),
        (0,3.1),
        (1,3.2),
        (2,3.3),
        (3,3.4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID','test_data'])
df = df.groupby('ID',sort=True).apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g['test_data'].values))

print(df)
df=df.unstack(level=-1).rename(columns=lambda x: 'test_data%s' %x)
print(df)
```

I have to use unstack(level=-1) because when we have uneven column size, the groupie and series stores the result as shown below.

```
ID   
0   0    1.1
    1    2.1
    2    3.1
1   0    1.2
    1    2.2
    2    3.2
2   0    1.3
    1    3.3
3   0    3.4
dtype: float64
```

End result I am getting after unstack is like below

```
    test_data0  test_data1  test_data2
ID                                    
0          1.1         2.1         3.1
1          1.2         2.2         3.2
2          1.3         3.3         NaN
3          3.4         NaN         NaN
```

but what I am expecting is

```
   test_data0 test_data1  test_data2
ID                                  
0         1.1        2.1           3.1
1         1.2        2.2           3.2
2         1.3        NAN           3.3
3         NAN        NAN           3.4
```

Let me know if there is any better way to do this other than groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if your dataframe is sorted as you show

```
df['num_zeros_seen'] = df['ID'].eq(0).cumsum()

#reshape the table
df = df.pivot(
    index='ID',
    columns='num_zeros_seen',
    values='test_data',
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
num_zeros_seen    1    2    3
ID                           
0               1.1  2.1  3.1
1               1.2  2.2  3.2
2               1.3  NaN  3.3
3               NaN  NaN  3.4
```

Comment: @mitoRibo- Actual test_data will have random floating point values. The above one was just an example to show how groupby reorders the value. Is there a way to create similar column as  df['before_decimal']  that increments every time it sees a zero?

Comment: @user1920591 thanks for explaining, I've edited the answer which no longer uses the floating point values. It DOES require the table to be sorted like your example to work. If it's in a different order you'll get a different answer